# Angular 6 and angular fire signInWithRedirect does not work on mobile browser

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular6

Thanks in advance.. still a newbie in web development.

I am exploring angular and firebase authentication. I could not find a better guide or tutorial where I can use authentication using angular fire.

my iphone browser chrome and safari don't allow me the login but on the desktop, it works.

I wanted to try the https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova
but I am lost and can't understand the documentation.

Appreciate all your help.

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
   import * as firebase from 'firebase';
   import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
    })

    export class AuthService {
    user$: Observable<firebase.User>;

     constructor( public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
     this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
    }

    login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new 
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    }

    logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    }

    redirectLogin() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.getRedirectResult();
    }

    isUserLoggedin(){
    return this.afAuth.authState;
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to use google login in my web apps in a long time on my chrome for android browser. Never have issues on chrome on my work desktop and no one else seems to have issues on their androids. Started working on a project at home today and now for some reason I cannot sign in on chrome on my home PC. No errors, no nothing. I can sign in once then get redirected back to my login page but never actually get anything. The redirect URL shows up in the address bar and then takes me right back to my login page. Tried private browser and I was able to login but took me right back to my log in page and never sees me as logged in.

Comment: I give up on this. but i will try again.. I got busy on doing CRUD on Firebase with a mix of filtering.

Comment: On my desktop it is Kaspersky causing the problem. I can pause protection and then log in. But I don't think that is the issue on my phone.